# In a new PC build, we get no post beep, but monitor asks for boot device

Tags: computer-building

In a dry-run hookup we don't have anything hooked up to any audio outputs, but on the connected monitor we get a message asking for us to select a boot device.

Does this mean that as far as we've gotten the mobo and parts are working correctly?

Comment: Things look good so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as far as you can tell so far. Next, hook up a keyboard and CD/DVD drive and boot a memtest86+ disk.